# Excel: A simpler way to sum a formula-based range besides INDIRECT() & ADDRESS()?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have a master value which defines how many columns to sum. So in the below image the master value is 4, which means I am summing D4:G4 (total 1100). If I changed the value to 8, it would sum D4:K4 (total 1700).

At the moment, I'm creating a large indirect address reference. Am I over-complicating this, or is this the simplest way?

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(D4),COLUMN(D4))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(D4),COLUMN(D4)+$B$1-1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INDEX, like this:

```
=SUM(D4:INDEX(D4:W4,,B1))
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! I assume that the value in B4 cannot be larger than the column width of the first index criteria (D4:W4)?

Comment: Right, so change the `W` as needed to match your setup, i.e. you could change that to XFD4 :)

Comment: @MrMusAddict if you think the answer is working for you just fine, please consider accepting it as the solution to your question by clicking the tick mark under the down-vote button next to this answer.